# Stack Overflow Tags and Synonyms Data Dump

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, data-dump

I've downloaded 2 different versions of the Stack Exchange data dump but it does not include any table for tags data.

How can I download a new Stack Overflow data dump with tags and their synonyms?